# print the first row(frozen row) and any range from the sheet under that row in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to print some data from a sheet that have a frozen row, and i want to print any range of data but i want the first row to get printed automatically every time i print something and i want to that with a button and here i mean with example:

the first row is frozen
and i want to print a range from a4 to d6
i want to have two cells and a button when i enter the range a4 and d6 to the two cells and press the button i get a pdf file contain the frozen row and the range i entered in the two cells (a4 and d6) is there any way to do that?

i tried a different method using the apps script but it was not flexible because i only can change the values from the code and here is the code i tried :

```
function print() {

  var spreadsheetsToProcess = [
    {
      spreadsheetId: SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL"),
      sheetName: "items",
      rangeA1Notation: "A1:D1"
    },
    {
      spreadsheetId: SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL"),
      sheetName: "items",
      rangeA1Notation: "A2:D6"
    }
  ];

  var file = getPDF(spreadsheetsToProcess);

  MailApp.sendEmail("****@GMAIL.com", 'Attachment example', 'Two spreadsheets at once.', {attachments:[file]});
}

function getPDF(spreadsheets) {
  
  var html = "<h2>"+ ss.getSheetByName('items').getName() +"</h2>";
  spreadsheets.forEach(spreadsheet => {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(spreadsheet.sheetName);
    var data = sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.rangeA1Notation).getValues();

    html += "<h3></h3><table style=' border: 1px solid yellow'>";
    data.forEach(row => {
      html += "<tr style='width: 175px ;border: 1px solid black'>";
      row.forEach(cell => {
        html += `<td style='width: 175px ;border: 1px solid black'>${cell}</td>`;
      })
      html += "</tr>";
    });
    html += "</table><br/>";
  })
  

  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var pdf = output.getAs('application/pdf').setName("export.pdf");

  return pdf;
}
```

i hope i was clear about everything

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From the following your sample situation,

> the first row is frozen and i want to print a range from a4 to d6 i want to have two cells and a button when i enter the range a4 and d6 to the two cells and press the button i get a pdf file contain the frozen row and the range i entered in the two cells (a4 and d6) is there any way to do that?

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to run your script of `print()` by giving the range values from 2 cells.

When I saw your script,

- I think that an error occurs at `var html = "<h2>"+ ss.getSheetByName('items').getName() +"</h2>";`. Because `ss` is not declared.
- It seems that `spreadsheetId: SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL"),` is not used.
- From your sample situation, I thought that the value of `spreadsheetsToProcess` can be used as a JSON object instead of an array.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the range values of "A4" and "D6" to the cells "E1:F1", respectively. And, please set the email address to `MailApp.sendEmail`. And, run the function of `print()`. If you want to run this script by clicking a button on Spreadsheet, please assign `print` to the button.

```js
function print() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit"; // Please set your Spreadsheet URL. This is from your showing script.
  var valueRange = "E1:F1"; // As a sample, the values of range are retrieved from "E1:F1". Please modify this for your actual situation.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var [a, b] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(valueRange).getValues()[0];
  var spreadsheetsToProcess = { sheetName: "items", rangeA1Notation: a + ":" + b };
  var file = getPDF(ss, spreadsheetsToProcess);
  MailApp.sendEmail("###", 'Attachment example', 'Two spreadsheets at once.', { attachments: [file] });
}

function getPDF(ss, { sheetName, rangeA1Notation }) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation).getValues();
  var html = "<h2>" + sheetName + "</h2>";
  html += "<h3></h3><table style=' border: 1px solid yellow'>";
  data.forEach(row => {
    html += "<tr style='width: 175px ;border: 1px solid black'>";
    row.forEach(cell => {
      html += `<td style='width: 175px ;border: 1px solid black'>${cell}</td>`;
    })
    html += "</tr>";
  });
  html += "</table><br/>";
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var pdf = output.getAs('application/pdf').setName("export.pdf");
  return pdf;
}
```

- When you run this script, the script of `print()` is run by retrieving the range values of "A4" and "D6" from the cells "E1:F1".

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR RESPONSE, ITRIED YOUR CODE BUT IT GIVES AN ERROR WITH ONE OF THE LINES, HERE IS THE MESSAGE :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

Comment: @Ahmed Zaqout Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null`, in this case, it is considered that the sheet name is required to be checked. So, please confirm the sheet name in the script and your Spreadsheet, again. If that was not the direct solution of your new issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, i will try  to confirm the the spreadsheet and sheet name

Answer (score 0):

HERE, I GOT IT TO WORK LOOK AT THE CODE @Tanaike

```
function print() {
  

  var spreadsheetsToProcess = [
    {
      spreadsheetId: SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL"),
      sheetName: "items",
      rangeA1Notation: "A1:D1"
    }
    
  ];

  var file = getPDF(spreadsheetsToProcess);

  MailApp.sendEmail("****@GMAIL.com", 'Attachment example', 'Two spreadsheets at once.', {attachments:[file]});


function getPDF(spreadsheets) {
  var html = "<h2>"+ sheetName +"</h2>";
  spreadsheets.forEach(spreadsheet => {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(spreadsheet.sheetName);
    var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,4).getValues();
    
    

    html += "<h3>Headers</h3><table style=' border: 1px solid yellow'>";
    data.forEach(row => {
      html += "<tr style='width: 200px ;border: 1px solid black'>";
      row.forEach(cell => {
        html += `<td style='width: 200px ;border: 1px solid black'>${cell}</td>`;
      })
      html += "</tr>";
    });
    html += "</table><br/>";
  })

  spreadsheets.forEach(spreadsheet => {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(spreadsheet.sheetName);
    var data1 = sheet.getRange(2,1,5,4).getValues();
    

    html += "<h3>Data</h3><table style=' border: 1px solid yellow'>";
    data1.forEach(row => {
      html += "<tr style='width: 200px ;border: 1px solid black'>";
      row.forEach(cell => {
        html += `<td style='width: 200px ;border: 1px solid black'>${cell}</td>`;
      })
      html += "</tr>";
    });
    html += "</table><br/>";
  })
  

  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var pdf = output.getAs('application/pdf').setName("export.pdf");

  return pdf;

  
}}
```